# Rails: Cannot reproduce XSS attack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss

I'm reading XSS security on [Rails Security](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss). In this page, there is an example of XSS:

```
<img src=javascript:alert('Hello')/>
<table background="avascript:alert('Hello'")>
</table>
```

I have added to my page. example `index.html.erb`. Then when I run this page, I checked html code. The code is displayed exactly but I don't see any dialog appear. Please tell me why.

Thanks

Comment: The guide is wrong. The browser doesn't run code in those places.

Comment: You're also missing a closing tag for <table

Comment: oh. I don't know that "the guide is wrong". If any. I don't know why down vote here :-?

Comment: @GrahamSlick yes. my bad. I have editted.

Comment: Old versions of IE used to run Javascript like that, but not anymore. The best practice is still to avoid these.